# Specifying thread Id in CUDA kernel in 3D

Tags: 3d, cuda, 2d

I am working to convert a 2D code to a 3D implementation

In 2D I have the following:

```
int row_number = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y
int column_number = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x
int threadId = row_number * grid_dimension + column_number
```

I'm trying to get this working in 3D

```
int row_number = 
int column_number =
int depth_number = 
int threadId = row_number * grid_dimension + column_number + depth_number * grid_dimension * grid_dimension
```

My first attempt has been this:

```
int row_number = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y
int column_number = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x
int depth_number = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z
int threadId = row_number * grid_dimension + column_number + depth_number * grid_dimension * grid_dimension
```

Is my expression for threadId in 3D correct and if not how do I get row, column, and depth numbers in 3D? I've seen expressions which just find the blockId and threadId directly but that's not quite what I have been looking for. If this is not the problem I might have other issues I need to investigate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined what you mean by `grid_dimension`.

Certainly these formulations are good to get row/column/depth indices:

```
unsigned int row_number = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
unsigned int column_number = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
unsigned int depth_number = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
```

To build up a globally unique thread id from the above variables, we could use:

```
unsigned long long idx = column_number + (row_number * gridDim.x) + (depth_number * (gridDim.x * gridDim.y);
```